# How to clean all entities from EntityManager?

Tags: java, jpa, ejb

I'm working on a JavaEE application with EJB and JPA.

I'm doing some tests and entities are persisting. Although, I'd like to remove entities between those tests. I tried to use the method *EntityManager.clear()* but this doesn't work. When I try to consult one of the old entities, it is still on the EntityManager.

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What kind of database you are using?

Comment: I'm using JavaDB and GlassFish, which JPA provider is EclipseLink

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invoking EntityManager.clear() will not remove the entities, because they are persisted in the database. 
You could close your entity manager factory and open again:

```
@Before
public void beforeTest() {
    entitManagerFactory.close()
    entitManagerFactory = // new EntityManagerFactory
}
```

The problem with this approach is that create an EntityManager may slow down the tests process.

What you could do instead is:

1) You could delete all entities before the test:

```
@Before
public void beforeTest() {
    // execute a query like delete from Person p
}
```

2) You could use a new ID/values for every test:

```
@Test
public void test1() {
    Person person = PersonTestUtil.createPerson("11111");
}

@Test
public void test2() {
    Person person = PersonTestUtil.createPerson("22222");
}
```

Comment: I'm sorry, but it's the first time that I work with this type of applications. Where do I put this code? I don't know if it's important, but I'm not using an EntityManagerFactory, I'm just using a EntityManager.

Comment: Are you not testing with junit? If not, just make sure to delete all the data once the server starts. Run a delete query before you start your test.